# How use main select column inside INNER JOIN SELECT

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT author, excitement, d.*, dist.* FROM profiles as p
INNER JOIN (SELECT id, ABS( excitement - 3.91) as exc_diff from profiles) as d ON p.id = d.id
INNER JOIN (SELECT count(id) as exc_dist from profiles where ABS( excitement - 3.91) < d.exc_diff) as dist;
```

How use main SELECT column inside INNER JOIN SELECT (Problem is with d.exc_diff it's say d.exc_diff unknown column;)

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT author, excitement, d.*, 
(SELECT count(id) from profiles where ABS( excitement - 3.91) < d.exc_diff) as exc_dist
FROM profiles as p
INNER JOIN (SELECT id, ABS( excitement - 3.91) as exc_diff from profiles) as d ON p.id = d.id;
```

Comment: Seems that was what i looked for :) (I had this before but i thought that results was incorrect)